# CamelCase Expansion in Vim like Intellij Idea?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, camelcasing

In Intellij Idea, there's a feature. Let's say I have used a variable `myCamelCase` somewhere in my code. Then if I type `mCC` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> or some such key combination, it expands to `myCamelCase`. Is there something similar in Vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, forgive me for answering twice, but since my first attempt missed the point, I'll have another go. This is more complicated than I thought, but possibly not as complicated as I have made it (!).

**This is now modified to suggest all matching variable names.**

First of all, here's a function to generate the 'mCC' abbreviation from the 'myCamelCase' string:

```
function! Camel_Initials(camel)
    let first_char = matchstr(a:camel,"^.")
    let other_char = substitute(a:camel,"\\U","","g")
    return first_char . other_char
endfunction
```

Now, here's a function that takes an abbreviation ('mCC') and scans the current buffer (backwards from the current line) for "words" that have this abbreviation. **A list of all matches is returned:**

```
function! Expand_Camel_Initials(abbrev)
    let winview=winsaveview()
    let candidate=a:abbrev
    let matches=[]
    try
        let resline = line(".")
        while resline >= 1
            let sstr = '\<' . matchstr(a:abbrev,"^.") . '[a-zA-Z]*\>'
            keepjumps let resline=search(sstr,"bW")
            let candidate=expand("<cword>")
            if candidate != a:abbrev && Camel_Initials(candidate) == a:abbrev
                call add( matches, candidate )
            endif
        endwhile
    finally
        call winrestview(winview)
        if len(matches) == 0
            echo "No expansion found"
        endif
        return sort(candidate)
    endtry
endfunction
```

Next, here's a custom-completion function that reads the word under the cursor and suggests the matches returned by the above functions:

```
function! Camel_Complete( findstart, base )
    if a:findstart
        let line = getline('.')
        let start = col('.') - 1
        while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '[A-Za-z_]'
            let start -= 1
        endwhile
        return start
    else
        return Expand_Camel_Initials( a:base )
    endif
endfunction
```

**To make use of this, you must define the "completefunc":**

```
setlocal completefunc=Camel_Complete
```

To use insert-mode completion, type <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL-U</kbd>, but I usually map this to <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd>:

```
inoremap <c-l> <c-x><c-u>
```

With this code in your vimrc you should find that typing `mCC` followed by <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> will make the expected replacement. If no matching expansion is found, the abbreviation is unchanged.

The code isn't water-tight, but it works in all the simple cases I tested. Hope it helps. Let me know if anything needs elucidating.

Comment: Amazing! That's all I can say. Still I am greedy/lazy enough to ask you for more. If there are more than one possible expansions : e.g. myCamelCase myCamelCart, the last one is chosen. Instead, can it be made to behave like Ctrl-P keyword completion in vim? Again, Amazing!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Handling multiple matches should just be a matter of getting Expand_Camel_Initials() to return a list of solutions and then setting the `completefunc` to let you choose between then. I'll try and have a look at it later this week.

Comment: Okay, it wasn't as painful as I thought... I have edited my answer and it should now work as you wish. Let me know if you have any problems (I haven't had a chance to test it properly).

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment. I will give it a try and feed you back. Is there a way to get notified for the comments?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this in Vim called [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish). Use the map `crc` to expand to camel case.